# Is there an way to remove an object which contains a property inside an array using arrayRemove() method?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I found out arrayUnion() and arrayRemove() method, which helps to append or remove things from array field of a document. However, arrayRemove() method only removes the exact input element. I want to take out all objects which key is a specified property. Is it possible to do that

ref.update({
  arrays: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({
    a: 1
  })
})

would not remove 
[{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: 2}] either, but I want to take out all a == 1 objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no operation provided by the SDK that will do this for you.  You will have to write code to read the document, iterate the elements of the array field, remove the ones you don't want, and write the new contents of the field back to the document.  Best to use a transaction for this.

Comment: Thanks!
At first, I wrote the code in transaction first but I thought I could make the code shorter.
Anyway, thanks for reply.